# Issue while adding different action buttons/menues on different fragments in dual pane view

Tags: android, toolbar

I have a screen with 2 different fragments ie dual pane view like tablets. I want to show different action menus for both the fragments in ToolBar.
I have inflated different menu.xml in onCreateOptionMenu method of each fragment with menu.clear. But on launch both fragments have same menu items.
I have defined ToolBar in each fragments layout xml.
Please let me know how both fragments will have different menus?
Thanks

Comment: update question with code